Split too large VBA into multiple Subs
How do you split a VBA code that is too long?
Below I show a snippet of the code. It takes up a lot of space because it has to repeat what is below, which is Dock III, for the other docks and now I wanted to add a bedding, but then the procedure became too long.
But I have tried putting the bedding in as another Sub, but it dosen't excecute the VBA in external Sub. Think it might be somting about the counter.
There may be some Danish in the code/notes 
Anyone that can help me in right direction?
Sub Booking()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Call Lav_Kalender_Ny 'Get the macro that creates the calendar

    Dim ws3 As Worksheet, ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, ws4 As Worksheet
    Dim PeriodeStart As Date, PeriodeSlut As Date, AnkomstVaerft As Date, AfgangVaerft As Date, AnkomstDok As Date, AbgangDok As Date
    Dim ProjectCount As Integer, Counter As Integer, Periode As Integer, PeriodeSkip As Integer, StartAnkomst As Integer, PeriodeDokSlut As Integer, RowCount As Long, PeriodeDok As Integer, ColumnCount As Integer, LineCount As Integer
    Dim Doc As String, WeekDay As String, laydaysDok3 As Integer, CounterStatistikDok As Integer

    Dim VDate As Boolean
    Set ws1 = Sheets("Indtastningsark")
    Set ws3 = Sheets("Vis_Oversigt")
    Set ws2 = Sheets("Statistik")
    Set ws4 = Sheets("MIS")

    VDate = IsDate(Range("C4"))

    If VDate = False Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    VDate = IsDate(Range("E4"))

    If VDate = False Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If ws3.Cells(4, 6) > 400 Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If ws3.Cells(4, 6) < 0 Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="5980"

    PeriodStart = ws3.Cells(4, 3).Value 'PeriodeStart is the start date for the calendar (entered on Vis_Oversigt)
    PeriodEnd = ws3.Cells(4, 5).Value 'PeriodeEnd is the end date for the calendar (entered on Vis_Oversigt)
    Period = ws3.Cells(4, 6) 'The period is the number of days that the calendar runs

    Counter = 7 ' Counter is set to 7, as the projects must be entered starting from row 7 on Vis_Oversigt
    ProjectCount = ws1.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'Finds the number of entered projects on the sheet Input sheet
    RowCount = ws3.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'Finds the number of entered rows on the sheet Vis_Oversigt

    ws3.Range(Cells(6, 1), Cells(RowCount, 9)).UnMerge
    ws3.Range(Cells(6, 1), Cells(RowCount, 9)).Clear 'Deletes retrieved projects on the sheet Vis_Oversigt
    ws3.Range(Cells(3, 1), Cells(RowCount + 6, 1)).RowHeight = 18

    ws3.Columns("A:A").NumberFormat = "@"

    ws4.Activate
    Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(5, 500)).Clear
    ws3.Activate
    laydaysDok3 = 0

    from Sheet Input sheet. Sorted by DOK/KAJ
    For j = 3 To ProjectCount
        AnkomstVaerft = ws1.Cells(j, 5).Value 'Time project arrives at shipyard
        AbgangVaerft = ws1.Cells(j, 6).Value 'Time ship departs from shipyard
        Dock = ws1.Cells(j, 7).Value 'Project's dock number or along quay
        AnkomstDok = ws1.Cells(j, 8).Value 'Time project goes into dock (if it does this)
        AbgangDok = ws1.Cells(j, 9).Value 'Time project leaves dock (if it does this)
        CounterStatistikDok = 0

        If (ArrivalDock >= PeriodStart And ArrivalDock <= PeriodEnd And Dock = "DOC III") Then 'Checks if arrival is within the period and that the ship must be in DOC xxx

            ws3.Range(Cells(Counter - 1, 1), Cells(Counter + 1, 1)).Merge
            ws3.Range(Cells(Counter - 1, 2), Cells(Counter + 1, 2)).Merge
            ws3.Range(Cells(Counter - 1, 3), Cells(Counter + 1, 3)).Merge
            ws3.Range(Cells(Counter - 1, 4), Cells(Counter + 1, 4)).Merge
            ws3.Range(Cells(Counter - 1, 5), Cells(Counter + 1, 5)).Merge
            ws3.Range(Cells(Counter - 1, 6), Cells(Counter + 1, 6)).Merge 
            ws3.Range(Cells(Counter - 1, 7), Cells(Counter + 1, 7)).Merge
            ws3.Range(Cells(Counter - 1, 8), Cells(Counter + 1, 8)).Merge

            ws3.Cells(Counter - 1, 1).Value = ws1.Cells(j, 1).Value 'Transfers values ​​from sheet Input sheet to Sheet Vis_Oversigt
            ws3.Cells(Counter - 1, 2).Value = ws1.Cells(j, 2).Value
            ws3.Cells(Counter - 1, 3).Value = ws1.Cells(j, 3).Value
            ws3.Cells(Counter - 1, 4).Value = ws1.Cells(j, 4).Value
            ws3.Cells(Counter - 1, 5).Value = ws1.Cells(j, 7).Value
            ws3.Cells(Counter - 1, 7).Value = ws1.Cells(j, 5).Value
            ws3.Cells(Counter - 1, 8).Value = ws1.Cells(j, 6).Value

            If PeriodEnd < DepartureYard Then 'Checks if the ship departs the yard after the calendar end date (this is done to avoid marking outside the calendar area)
                PeriodShip = Period 'PeriodShip is defined to be the same time period as the calendar (just to avoid marking outside the calendar area)
            Else
                PeriodShip = ws1.Cells(j, 6) - PeriodStart 'If the ship departs the yard before the calendar ends, PeriodShip is defined to be from the start date of the calendar to the ship departure
            End If

            ws3.Range(Cells(Counter, ((ArrivalYard - PeriodStart) + 10)), Cells(Counter, PeriodShip + 10)).Interior.ColorIndex = 5 'Colors the range blue in calendar

            If ArrivalDoc <> "00:00:00" And DepartureDoc <> "00:00:00" Then 'Checks if the ship is scheduled to dock
                If ArrivalDoc >= PeriodStart And ArrivalDoc <= PeriodEnd Then 'Checks if the arrival is within the calendar period
                    If PeriodEnd <= DepartureDoc Then 'Checks if the docking period runs the entire calendar period
                        PeriodEndDoc = Period
                    ElseIf PeriodEnd >= DepartureDoc Then 'Checks if the docking period expires before the calendar period
                        PeriodEndDoc = ws1.Cells(j, 9) - PeriodStart
                    End If

                    ws3.Range(Cells(Counter, ((ArrivalDoc - PeriodStart) + 10)), Cells(Counter, PeriodEndDoc + 10)).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
                    ws4.Activate
                    Range(Cells(1, ((ArrivalDoc - PeriodStart) + 1)), Cells(1, PeriodDokEnd + 1)).Value = 1
                    ws3.Activate
                    'CounterStatisticDok = PeriodDokEnd - (ArrivalDok - PeriodStart) 'TY

                Than If
            Than If

            Counter = Counter + 3 'advances counter and skips line

        ElseIf PeriodStart > Arrival Yard And PeriodEnd < Departure Yard And Dock = "DOK III" Then

            ws3.Range(Cells(Counter - 1, 1), Cells(Counter + 1, 1)).Merge
            ws3.Range(Cells(Counter - 1, 2), Cells(Counter + 1, 2)).Merge
            ws3.Range(Cells(Counter - 1, 3), Cells(Counter + 1, 3)).Merge
            ws3.Range(Cells(Counter - 1, 4), Cells(Counter + 1, 4)).Merge
            ws3.Range(Cells(Counter - 1, 5), Cells(Counter + 1, 5)).Merge
            ws3.Range(Cells(Counter - 1, 6), Cells(Counter + 1, 6)).Merge
            ws3.Range(Cells(Counter - 1, 7), Cells(Counter + 1, 7)).Merge
            ws3.Range(Cells(Counter - 1, 8), Cells(Counter + 1, 8)).Merge

            ws3.Cells(Counter - 1, 1).Value = ws1.Cells(j, 1).Value 'Transfers values ​​from sheet Input sheet to Sheet Vis_Oversigt
            ws3.Cells(Counter - 1, 2).Value = ws1.Cells(j, 2).Value
            ws3.Cells(Counter - 1, 3).Value = ws1.Cells(j, 3).Value
            ws3.Cells(Counter - 1, 4).Value = ws1.Cells(j, 4).Value
            ws3.Cells(Counter - 1, 5).Value = ws1.Cells(j, 7).Value
            ws3.Cells(Counter - 1, 7).Value = ws1.Cells(j, 5).Value
            ws3.Cells(Counter - 1, 8).Value = ws1.Cells(j, 6).Value

            Range(Cells(Counter, 10), Cells(Counter, Period + 10)).Interior.ColorIndex = 5

            If AnkomstDok <> "00:00:00" And AfgangDok <> "00:00:00" Then 
                If PeriodeStart >= AnkomstDok And PeriodeSlut <= AfgangDok Then 
                    Range(Cells(Counter, 10), Cells(Counter, Periode + 10)).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
                    ws4.Activate
                    Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, Periode + 1)).Value = 1
                    ws3.Activate
                    'CounterStatistikDok = Periode
                End If

                If AnkomstDok >= PeriodeStart And AnkomstDok <= PeriodeSlut Then 
                    If PeriodeSlut <= AfgangDok Then
                        PeriodeDokSlut = Periode
                    ElseIf PeriodeSlut > AfgangDok Then
                        PeriodeDokSlut = ws1.Cells(j, 9) - PeriodeStart
                    End If

                    ws3.Range(Cells(Counter, ((AnkomstDok - PeriodeStart) + 10)), Cells(Counter, PeriodeDokSlut + 10)).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
                    ws4.Activate
                    ws4.Range(Cells(1, ((AnkomstDok - PeriodeStart) + 1)), Cells(1, PeriodeDokSlut + 1)).Value = 1
                    ws3.Activate
                    'CounterStatistikDok = (AnkomstDok - PeriodeStart) - PeriodeDokSlut
                End If

                If AnkomstDok < PeriodeStart And AfgangDok <= PeriodeSlut Then
                    Range(Cells(Counter, 10), Cells(Counter, (AfgangDok - PeriodeStart) + 10)).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
                    ws4.Activate
                    Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, (AfgangDok - PeriodeStart) + 1)).Value = 1
                    ws3.Activate
                    'CounterStatistikDok = (AfgangDok - PeriodeStart)
                End If

            End If
            Counter = Counter + 3

        ElseIf AfgangVaerft >= PeriodeStart And AfgangVaerft <= PeriodeSlut And AnkomstVaerft < PeriodeStart And Dok = "DOK III" Then
            ws3.Range(Cells(Counter - 1, 1), Cells(Counter + 1, 1)).Merge
            ws3.Range(Cells(Counter - 1, 2), Cells(Counter + 1, 2)).Merge
            ws3.Range(Cells(Counter - 1, 3), Cells(Counter + 1, 3)).Merge
            ws3.Range(Cells(Counter - 1, 4), Cells(Counter + 1, 4)).Merge
            ws3.Range(Cells(Counter - 1, 5), Cells(Counter + 1, 5)).Merge
            ws3.Range(Cells(Counter - 1, 6), Cells(Counter + 1, 6)).Merge
            ws3.Range(Cells(Counter - 1, 7), Cells(Counter + 1, 7)).Merge
            ws3.Range(Cells(Counter - 1, 8), Cells(Counter + 1, 8)).Merge

            ws3.Cells(Counter - 1, 1).Value = ws1.Cells(j, 1).Value 'Overfører værdier fra sheet Indtastningsark til Sheet Vis_Oversigt
            ws3.Cells(Counter - 1, 2).Value = ws1.Cells(j, 2).Value
            ws3.Cells(Counter - 1, 3).Value = ws1.Cells(j, 3).Value
            ws3.Cells(Counter - 1, 4).Value = ws1.Cells(j, 4).Value
            ws3.Cells(Counter - 1, 5).Value = ws1.Cells(j, 7).Value
            ws3.Cells(Counter - 1, 7).Value = ws1.Cells(j, 5).Value
            ws3.Cells(Counter - 1, 8).Value = ws1.Cells(j, 6).Value
            Range(Cells(Counter, 10), Cells(Counter, (AfgangVaerft - PeriodeStart) + 10)).Interior.ColorIndex = 5

            If AnkomstDok <> "00:00:00" And AfgangDok <> "00:00:00" Then 'Tjekker om skibet er sat til at skulle i dok
                If PeriodeStart >= AnkomstDok And AfgangDok >= PeriodeStart Then 'Tjekker om kalenderperioden optræder i værftsperioden
                    Range(Cells(Counter, 10), Cells(Counter, ((AfgangDok - PeriodeStart) + 10))).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
                    ws4.Activate
                    Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, ((AfgangDok - PeriodeStart) + 1))).Value = 1
                    ws3.Activate
                    'CounterStatistikDok = (AfgangDok - PeriodeStart)
                End If

                If AnkomstDok >= PeriodeStart Then 'Tjekker om ankomsten ligger inden for kalenderperioden
                    ws3.Range(Cells(Counter, ((AnkomstDok - PeriodeStart) + 10)), Cells(Counter, (AfgangDok - PeriodeStart) + 10)).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
                    ws4.Activate
                    Range(Cells(1, ((AnkomstDok - PeriodeStart) + 1)), Cells(1, (AfgangDok - PeriodeStart) + 1)).Value = 1
                    ws3.Activate
                    'CounterStatistikDok = (AfgangDok - PeriodeStart) - (AnkomstDok - PeriodeStart)
                End If

                If AnkomstDok <= PeriodeStart And AfgangDok > PeriodeStart Then
                    Range(Cells(Counter, 10), Cells(Counter, (AfgangDok - PeriodeStart) + 10)).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
                    ws4.Activate
                    Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, (AfgangDok - PeriodeStart) + 1)).Value = 1
                    ws3.Activate
                    'CounterStatistikDok = (AfgangDok - PeriodeStart)
                End If

            End If
            Counter = Counter + 3

        End If
        'If CounterStatistikDok > 0 Then
        CounterStatistikDok = CounterStatistikDok + 1
        'End If

        'laydaysDok3 = laydaysDok3 + CounterStatistikDok
        'ws2.Cells(5, 2).Value = laydaysDok3
        'ws2.Cells(5, 2).Value = Excel.WorksheetFunction.Sum(ws4.Range("A1:A500"))
         
    Next j

    Call Bedding




And below almost the same as above, for the next docks.
I have tried making Sub for Bedding with and without what is above the line with the text: 'Here follows the algorithm for Bedding
Sub for bedding:

Sub Bedding()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Call Lav_Kalender_Ny 'Get the macro that creates the calendar

    Dim ws3 As Worksheet, ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, ws4 As Worksheet
    Dim PeriodeStart As Date, PeriodeSlut As Date, AnkomstVaerft As Date, AfgangVaerft As Date, AnkomstDok As Date, AfgangDok As Date
    Dim ProjectCount As Integer, Counter As Integer, Periode As Integer, PeriodeSkib As Integer, StartAnkomst As Integer, PeriodeDokSlut As Integer, RowCount As Long, PeriodeDok As Integer, ColumnCount As Integer, LineCount As Integer
    Dim Dok As String, WeekDay As String, laydaysDok3 As Integer, CounterStatistikDok As Integer

    Dim VDate As Boolean
    Set ws1 = Sheets("Indtastningsark")
    Set ws3 = Sheets("Vis_Oversigt")
    Set ws2 = Sheets("Statistik")
    Set ws4 = Sheets("MIS")

    VDate = IsDate(Range("C4"))

    If VDate = False Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    VDate = IsDate(Range("E4"))
     
    If VDate = False Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If ws3.Cells(4, 6) > 400 Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If ws3.Cells(4, 6) < 0 Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'Her følger algortimen for Bedding

    For j = 3 To ProjectCount
        AnkomstVaerft = ws1.Cells(j, 5).Value
        AfgangVaerft = ws1.Cells(j, 6).Value
        Dok = ws1.Cells(j, 7).Value
        AnkomstDok = ws1.Cells(j, 8).Value '
        AfgangDok = ws1.Cells(j, 9).Value
        If (AnkomstVaerft >= PeriodeStart And AnkomstVaerft <= PeriodeSlut And Dok = "Bedding") Then
            ws3.Range(Cells(Counter - 1, 1), Cells(Counter + 1, 1)).Merge
            ws3.Range(Cells(Counter - 1, 2), Cells(Counter + 1, 2)).Merge
            ws3.Range(Cells(Counter - 1, 3), Cells(Counter + 1, 3)).Merge
            ws3.Range(Cells(Counter - 1, 4), Cells(Counter + 1, 4)).Merge
            ws3.Range(Cells(Counter - 1, 5), Cells(Counter + 1, 5)).Merge
            ws3.Range(Cells(Counter - 1, 6), Cells(Counter + 1, 6)).Merge
            ws3.Range(Cells(Counter - 1, 7), Cells(Counter + 1, 7)).Merge
            ws3.Range(Cells(Counter - 1, 8), Cells(Counter + 1, 8)).Merge

            ws3.Cells(Counter - 1, 1).Value = ws1.Cells(j, 1).Value 'Overfører værdier fra sheet Indtastningsark til Sheet Vis_Oversigt
            ws3.Cells(Counter - 1, 2).Value = ws1.Cells(j, 2).Value
            ws3.Cells(Counter - 1, 3).Value = ws1.Cells(j, 3).Value
            ws3.Cells(Counter - 1, 4).Value = ws1.Cells(j, 4).Value
            ws3.Cells(Counter - 1, 5).Value = ws1.Cells(j, 7).Value
            ws3.Cells(Counter - 1, 7).Value = ws1.Cells(j, 5).Value
            ws3.Cells(Counter - 1, 8).Value = ws1.Cells(j, 6).Value

            If PeriodeSlut < AfgangVaerft Then
                PeriodeSkib = Periode
            Else
                PeriodeSkib = ws1.Cells(j, 6) - PeriodeStart
            End If

            ws3.Range(Cells(Counter, ((AnkomstVaerft - PeriodeStart) + 10)), Cells(Counter, PeriodeSkib + 10)).Interior.ColorIndex = 5 'Farver Rangen blå i kalenderen

            If AnkomstDok <> "00:00:00" And AfgangDok <> "00:00:00" Then
                If AnkomstDok >= PeriodeStart And AnkomstDok <= PeriodeSlut Then
                    If PeriodeSlut <= AfgangDok Then
                        PeriodeDokSlut = Periode
                    ElseIf PeriodeSlut >= AfgangDok Then
                        PeriodeDokSlut = ws1.Cells(j, 9) - PeriodeStart
                    End If

                    ws3.Range(Cells(Counter, ((AnkomstDok - PeriodeStart) + 10)), Cells(Counter, PeriodeDokSlut + 10)).Interior.ColorIndex = 43

                    ws4.Activate
                    Range(Cells(2, ((AnkomstDok - PeriodeStart) + 1)), Cells(2, PeriodeDokSlut + 1)).Value = 1
                    ws3.Activate

                End If
            End If

            Counter = Counter + 3
        ElseIf PeriodeStart >= AnkomstVaerft And PeriodeSlut <= AfgangVaerft And Dok = "Bedding" Then
            ws3.Range(Cells(Counter - 1, 1), Cells(Counter + 1, 1)).Merge
            ws3.Range(Cells(Counter - 1, 2), Cells(Counter + 1, 2)).Merge
            ws3.Range(Cells(Counter - 1, 3), Cells(Counter + 1, 3)).Merge
            ws3.Range(Cells(Counter - 1, 4), Cells(Counter + 1, 4)).Merge
            ws3.Range(Cells(Counter - 1, 5), Cells(Counter + 1, 5)).Merge
            ws3.Range(Cells(Counter - 1, 6), Cells(Counter + 1, 6)).Merge
            ws3.Range(Cells(Counter - 1, 7), Cells(Counter + 1, 7)).Merge
            ws3.Range(Cells(Counter - 1, 8), Cells(Counter + 1, 8)).Merge

            ws3.Cells(Counter - 1, 1).Value = ws1.Cells(j, 1).Value
            ws3.Cells(Counter - 1, 2).Value = ws1.Cells(j, 2).Value
            ws3.Cells(Counter - 1, 3).Value = ws1.Cells(j, 3).Value
            ws3.Cells(Counter - 1, 4).Value = ws1.Cells(j, 4).Value
            ws3.Cells(Counter - 1, 5).Value = ws1.Cells(j, 7).Value
            ws3.Cells(Counter - 1, 7).Value = ws1.Cells(j, 5).Value
            ws3.Cells(Counter - 1, 8).Value = ws1.Cells(j, 6).Value

            Range(Cells(Counter, 10), Cells(Counter, Periode + 10)).Interior.ColorIndex = 5

            If AnkomstDok <> "00:00:00" And AfgangDok <> "00:00:00" Then
                If PeriodeStart >= AnkomstDok And PeriodeSlut <= AfgangDok Then
                    Range(Cells(Counter, 10), Cells(Counter, Periode + 10)).Interior.ColorIndex = 43
                    ws4.Activate
                    Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(2, Periode + 1)).Value = 1
                    ws3.Activate
                End If

                If AnkomstDok >= PeriodeStart And AnkomstDok <= PeriodeSlut Then
                    If PeriodeSlut <= AfgangDok Then
                        PeriodeDokSlut = Periode
                    ElseIf PeriodeSlut > AfgangDok Then
                        PeriodeDokSlut = ws1.Cells(j, 9) - PeriodeStart
                    End If

                    ws3.Range(Cells(Counter, ((AnkomstDok - PeriodeStart) + 10)), Cells(Counter, PeriodeDokSlut + 10)).Interior.ColorIndex = 43

                    ws4.Activate
                    ws4.Range(Cells(2, ((AnkomstDok - PeriodeStart) + 1)), Cells(2, PeriodeDokSlut + 1)).Value = 1
                    ws3.Activate

                End If

                If AnkomstDok < PeriodeStart And AfgangDok <= PeriodeSlut Then
                    Range(Cells(Counter, 10), Cells(Counter, (AfgangDok - PeriodeStart) + 10)).Interior.ColorIndex = 43

                    ws4.Activate
                    Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(2, (AfgangDok - PeriodeStart) + 1)).Value = 1
                    ws3.Activate
                End If

            End If
            Counter = Counter + 3

        ElseIf AfgangVaerft >= PeriodeStart And AfgangVaerft <= PeriodeSlut And AnkomstVaerft < PeriodeStart And Dok = "Bedding" Then
            ws3.Range(Cells(Counter - 1, 1), Cells(Counter + 1, 1)).Merge
            ws3.Range(Cells(Counter - 1, 2), Cells(Counter + 1, 2)).Merge
            ws3.Range(Cells(Counter - 1, 3), Cells(Counter + 1, 3)).Merge
            ws3.Range(Cells(Counter - 1, 4), Cells(Counter + 1, 4)).Merge
            ws3.Range(Cells(Counter - 1, 5), Cells(Counter + 1, 5)).Merge
            ws3.Range(Cells(Counter - 1, 6), Cells(Counter + 1, 6)).Merge
            ws3.Range(Cells(Counter - 1, 7), Cells(Counter + 1, 7)).Merge
            ws3.Range(Cells(Counter - 1, 8), Cells(Counter + 1, 8)).Merge

            ws3.Cells(Counter - 1, 1).Value = ws1.Cells(j, 1).Value
            ws3.Cells(Counter - 1, 2).Value = ws1.Cells(j, 2).Value
            ws3.Cells(Counter - 1, 3).Value = ws1.Cells(j, 3).Value
            ws3.Cells(Counter - 1, 4).Value = ws1.Cells(j, 4).Value
            ws3.Cells(Counter - 1, 5).Value = ws1.Cells(j, 7).Value
            ws3.Cells(Counter - 1, 7).Value = ws1.Cells(j, 5).Value
            ws3.Cells(Counter - 1, 8).Value = ws1.Cells(j, 6).Value

            Range(Cells(Counter, 10), Cells(Counter, (AfgangVaerft - PeriodeStart) + 10)).Interior.ColorIndex = 5

            If AnkomstDok <> "00:00:00" And AfgangDok <> "00:00:00" Then 'Tjekker om skibet er sat til at skulle i dok
                If PeriodeStart >= AnkomstDok And AfgangDok >= PeriodeStart Then
                    Range(Cells(Counter, 10), Cells(Counter, (AfgangDok - PeriodeStart) + 10)).Interior.ColorIndex = 43

                    ws4.Activate
                    Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(2, ((AfgangDok - PeriodeStart) + 1))).Value = 1
                    ws3.Activate

                End If

                If AnkomstDok >= PeriodeStart Then

                    ws3.Range(Cells(Counter, ((AnkomstDok - PeriodeStart) + 10)), Cells(Counter, (AfgangDok - PeriodeStart) + 10)).Interior.ColorIndex = 43

                    ws4.Activate
                    Range(Cells(2, ((AnkomstDok - PeriodeStart) + 1)), Cells(2, (AfgangDok - PeriodeStart) + 1)).Value = 1
                    ws3.Activate

                End If

                If AnkomstDok <= PeriodeStart And AfgangDok > PeriodeStart Then
                    Range(Cells(Counter, 10), Cells(Counter, (AfgangDok - PeriodeStart) + 10)).Interior.ColorIndex = 43

                    ws4.Activate
                    Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(2, (AfgangDok - PeriodeStart) + 1)).Value = 1
                    ws3.Activate

                End If

            End If
            Counter = Counter + 3

        End If

    Next j

End Sub

I've tried splitting the VBA into several, but I think there's a problem with the counter.
I'm not a super user of codes, so I don't really know how to split this up into several Subs.

I suggest you do a bit more learning on how to structure code, in particular how to use functions and subroutines to subdivide your code. Follow a coding course, do some practice on coding layout and structure, so you can abstract a structure from your problem. Then incrementally address the problem step by step, gradually extending the functions to encompass more of the application. Quite quickly you will get skilled at it.

Please fix your formatting. You added the code as a block quote (the > signs), and then formatted it as code. This makes it unusable because of the > at the beginning of each line. Please edit to remove those > characters, so that your code can be copied and pasted and used directly.

Should the 2 Than If be End If ?

If you only need an incremental counter, a ByRef argument will work for your case. Changes made to the parameter in the called procedure will affect the variable in the calling procedure. eg. Sub Bedding(ByRef Counter As Long)

For a start you could replace these repeating blocks
  ws3.Range(Cells(counter - 1, 1), Cells(counter + 1, 1)).Merge
  ws3.Range(Cells(counter - 1, 2), Cells(counter + 1, 2)).Merge
  ws3.Range(Cells(counter - 1, 3), Cells(counter + 1, 3)).Merge
  ws3.Range(Cells(counter - 1, 4), Cells(counter + 1, 4)).Merge
  ws3.Range(Cells(counter - 1, 5), Cells(counter + 1, 5)).Merge
  ws3.Range(Cells(counter - 1, 6), Cells(counter + 1, 6)).Merge
  ws3.Range(Cells(counter - 1, 7), Cells(counter + 1, 7)).Merge
  ws3.Range(Cells(counter - 1, 8), Cells(counter + 1, 8)).Merge

  ws3.Cells(counter - 1, 1).Value = ws1.Cells(j, 1).Value
  ws3.Cells(counter - 1, 2).Value = ws1.Cells(j, 2).Value
  ws3.Cells(counter - 1, 3).Value = ws1.Cells(j, 3).Value
  ws3.Cells(counter - 1, 4).Value = ws1.Cells(j, 4).Value
  ws3.Cells(counter - 1, 7).Value = ws1.Cells(j, 5).Value
  ws3.Cells(counter - 1, 8).Value = ws1.Cells(j, 6).Value
  ws3.Cells(counter - 1, 5).Value = ws1.Cells(j, 7).Value

With calls to a sub
Call TransferData(ws1.Cells(j, 1), ws3.Cells(counter - 1, 1))

Sub TransferData(rngFrom, rngTo)

   Dim c As Long, arMap
   For c = 1 To 8
       rngTo.Offset(0, c - 1).Resize(3).Merge
   Next
   arMap = Array(0, 1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 4)
   For c = 1 To 7
       rngTo.Offset(0, arMap(c - 1)) = rngFrom.Offset(0, c - 1)
   Next

End Sub


Not sure all the logic is correct but hopefully  you get the idea
Option Explicit

Sub ProcessAllDocks()
    Dim id, n As Long, targetRow As Long, LastRow As Long
        
    'Call Lav_Kalender_Ny 'Get the macro that creates the calendar

    ' clear old data
    With ThisWorkbook
        With .Sheets("Vis_Oversigt")
            ' check valid dates
            If IsDate(.Range("C4")) = False Or IsDate(.Range("E4")) = False Then
                MsgBox "Date error in C4 or E4", vbExclamation
                Exit Sub
            ElseIf .Range("F6") > 400 Or .Range("F6") < 0 Then
                MsgBox "F6 >400 or <0", vbExclamation
                Exit Sub
            End If
            
            .Unprotect Password:="5980"
            LastRow = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            If LastRow >= 6 Then
                .Range("A6:I" & LastRow).UnMerge
                .Rows("6:" & LastRow + 2).Clear
            End If
            .Rows("3:" & LastRow + 2).RowHeight = 18
            .Columns("A:A").NumberFormat = "@"
        End With
        With .Sheets("MIS")
            .UsedRange.Clear
        End With
    End With
    
    ' process each dock
    targetRow = 7
    For Each id In Array("DOC III", "Bedding")
       n = n + 1
       Call ProcessDock(n, CStr(id), targetRow)
    Next
    MsgBox n & " docks processed", vbInformation
    
End Sub
       
Sub ProcessDock(n As Long, dockID, ByRef targetRow)

    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, ws3 As Worksheet, ws4 As Worksheet
    Dim LastProjectRow As Long, r As Long, dock As String
    
    Dim dtCalStart As Date, dtCalEnd As Date
    Dim dtArrive As Date, dtDepart As Date ' yard
    Dim dtEntry As Date, dtExit As Date ' dock
    Dim bInYard As Boolean, bInDock As Boolean
    
    With ThisWorkbook
        Set ws1 = .Sheets("Indtastningsark") ' Project entry sheet
        Set ws2 = .Sheets("Statistik") 'Statistics
        Set ws3 = .Sheets("Vis_Oversigt") ' Overview
        Set ws4 = .Sheets("MIS") '
    End With
    
    ' Vis_Oversigt
    With ws3
        'start date for the calendar
        dtCalStart = ws3.Cells(4, 3).Value
        'end date for the calendar
        dtCalEnd = ws3.Cells(4, 5).Value
    End With
        
    ' ws1 - Project Entry Sheet. Sorted by DOK/KAJ
    ' Finds the number of entered projects on the Input sheet
    LastProjectRow = ws1.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    
    ' Scan each project
    For r = 3 To LastProjectRow
        ' check dock ID
        If ws1.Cells(r, "G").Value = dockID Then 'Project's dock number or along quay
    
            With ws1
                dtArrive = .Cells(r, "E").Value 'Time ship arrives at shipyard
                dtDepart = .Cells(r, "F").Value 'Time ship departs from shipyard
                dtEntry = .Cells(r, "H").Value 'Time ship goes into dock (if it does this)
                dtExit = .Cells(r, "I").Value 'Time ship leaves dock (if it does this)
            End With
            bInYard = False
            bInDock = False

            ' Checks if Arrival in Dock ?? is within the period
            If (dtArrive >= dtCalStart) And (dtArrive <= dtCalEnd) Then
                bInYard = True
                                                 
                'Checks if the ship is scheduled to dock
                If dtEntry <> "00:00:00" And dtExit <> "00:00:00" Then
                    'Checks if the arrival is within the calendar period
                    If dtEntry >= dtCalStart And dtEntry <= dtCalEnd Then
                        bInDock = True
                    End If
                End If

            ' Check if Arrival is before Period and Departs after Period
            ElseIf (dtArrive < dtCalStart) And (dtDepart > dtCalEnd) Then
                bInYard = True
                
                ' color dock red=3
                If dtEntry <> "00:00:00" And dtExit <> "00:00:00" Then
                    If dtEntry <= dtCalStart And dtExit >= dtCalEnd Then
                        bInDock = True
                    ElseIf dtEntry >= dtCalStart And dtEntry <= dtCalEnd Then
                        bInDock = True
                    ElseIf dtEntry < dtCalStart And dtExit <= dtCalEnd Then
                        bInDock = True
                    End If
                End If
                                    
            ' Check if Arrival is before Period and Exits Dock within Period
            ElseIf dtArrive < dtCalStart _
               And dtExit >= dtCalStart And dtExit <= dtCalEnd Then
                bInYard = True

                'Tjekker om skibet er sat til at skulle i dok
                'Checks whether the ship is set to dock
                If dtEntry <> "00:00:00" And dtExit <> "00:00:00" Then
                    'Tjekker om kalenderperioden optræder i værftsperioden
                    'Checks whether the calendar period appears in the yard period
                    If dtEntry <= dtCalStart And dtExit >= dtCalEnd Then
                        bInDock = True
                    'Tjekker om ankomsten ligger inden for kalenderperioden
                    'Checks whether the arrival is within the calendar period
                    ElseIf dtEntry >= dtCalStart Then
                        bInDock = True
                    ElseIf dtEntry <= dtCalStart And dtExit > dtCalStart Then
                        bInDock = True
                    End If
                End If
            End If
            
            ' transfer data
            If bInYard Then
                Call TransferData(ws1.Cells(r, 1), ws3.Cells(targetRow - 1, 1))
                ' Fill Calendar with in yard dates 5-Blue
                Call FillCalendar(5, ws3.Cells(targetRow, "J"), dtArrive, dtDepart, dtCalStart, dtCalEnd)

                If bInDock Then
                    ' Fill calendar with in dock dates red-3 and MIS with 1's
                    Call FillCalendar(3, ws3.Cells(targetRow, "J"), dtEntry, dtExit, dtCalStart, dtCalEnd, ws4.Cells(n, 1))
                End If
                                   
                targetRow = targetRow + 3
            End If

        End If
    Next
   
    MsgBox dockID & " Processed", vbInformation
End Sub

Sub TransferData(rngFrom, rngTo)

   Dim c As Long, arMap
   For c = 1 To 8
       rngTo.Offset(0, c - 1).Resize(3).Merge
   Next
   arMap = Array(0, 1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 4)
   For c = 1 To 7
       rngTo.Offset(0, arMap(c - 1)) = rngFrom.Offset(0, c - 1)
   Next

End Sub

Sub FillCalendar(iColor, rng, dtStart, dtEnd, dtCalStart, dtCalEnd, Optional rngMIS)
 
    Dim dt1 As Date, dt2 As Date
    
    ' constrain start date to calendar start
    dt1 = IIf(dtStart < dtCalStart, dtCalStart, dtStart)
    ' constrain end date to calendar end
    dt2 = IIf(dtEnd > dtCalEnd, dtCalEnd, dtEnd)
    ' fill cells
    rng.Offset(0, dt1 - dtCalStart).Resize(, dt2 - dt1 + 1).Interior.ColorIndex = iColor
    
    ' markup MIS
    If IsMissing(rngMIS) Then
       ' skip
    Else
        rngMIS.Offset(0, dt1 - dtCalStart).Resize(, dt2 - dt1 + 1) = 1
    End If

End Sub



CDP1802
You hit the spot with what I was looking for.
Thank you so much

@Gaasen - welcome to SO; if this "hit the spot" feel free to mark this answer as "accepted", by ticking the hollow green checkmark just underneath the voting buttons, near the top of this answer
C.f. "Someone answers". Furthermore it helps others coming along later to see there's a working answer.

@CDP1802 - The first answer with the Sub worked 100%
I'll have to study the coding you have done below, I'm not that good in coding
Is it a re-coding of the original Sub?
Here the spreadsheet are with the first answer you supported with we.____tl/t-D6W5ddXQRc
Remove the ____ and copy to browser

@T.M.
Yes, you're right!
Im new in this forum, so have to study and learn.
Thanks for informing me

@Gaasen My update is a  refactoring of your original code adding a new sub  ProcessAllDocks() to run ProcessDock() for DOC III and then Bedding

@CDP1802 I see, it's splitted up in more Sub's, result even less main sub code

@Gaasen I have refactored code into 5 modules. Take a copy of your workbook , delete all existing modules and import new ones. Add a sheet called Run Log and assign button to first 3 subs in MTasks link here  we._____tl/t-EJIHmCmUCt

@CDP1802 Sorry i have missed your upload
I have studied your Sub codes and it works fine, great job
Many thanks for putting your comments in the Sub, so I can see what the codes are doing.
Only thing is, that we need to have different colors for each docks (3 docks and 1 bedding).

@Gaasen Try this link we._____tl/t-bnWkEquh8u

@1802, I don't know if I'm allowed to swear here, but shit, it's running fast now....
I've messed around with it a bit, so it fits our needs, even though you were 99% spot on.
That's some great programming you've done.
Now I could see that there's something called Sub and Private Sub
Thank you so much for the great work
